Separar contenido de una celda de mysql en laravel
me podrían ayudar en como puedo separar el contenido de una celda de mi base de datos, un ejemplo, al momento de imprimir en mi pagina web, un ejemplo:
en mi base de datos, tengo dos columnas, una de numero de errores y otra de observaciones, en la de errores coloco 2 vale y en observaciones describo esas observación,

errores de ortografía.
falta jpg de comprobante.

esos se guarda en la base de datos, en la misma columna, pero cuando lo imprimo en mi pagina web, aparece todo de corrido, me podrían ayudar.
class EnviarController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $yo = Auth::user()->identification;
        $cargos = Auth::user()->charge;

        $miLista = Revision::where('remitente', $yo)->paginate(5);

        $productos = Category::where('sector', $cargos)->select('product')->orderBy('product', 'asc')->get();

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return view('partials.tableRevision', compact('miLista'))->render();
        }

        return view('enviar', compact('miLista', 'productos'));
    }
}


Muestra una imagen de las columnas de la base de datos, por que no me queda claro como estan ahora.

O sea, si entendí bien, quieres usar una sola columna para guardar dos valores ¿? Si los datos son distintos, crea una columna para cada dato, que no te cobran millones por definir columnas, en cambio, si mezclas todo en uno, lo que crees que es ahorro se convierte en un costo altísimo ... ya lo vas viendo precisamente con la dificultad actual y vendrán cosas peores, cuando tengas que filtrar datos, ordenarlos, agruparlos, relacionarlos con otras tablas, etc. No, las bases de datos no funcionan definiendo de una forma rácana las columnas.

Hay otra forma más eficiente de hacerlo y es creando una tabla intermedia en la que se almacena un registro por cada error y se relacionan con el OID de la tabla principal. Luego para mostrar los errores por separado utilizas un ciclo y si necesitas mostrar la cantidad de errores usas la función count().
